# Casting to objects having properties with same names

Tags: simple.data

I have a problem when i try to cast to class Foo having Bar property. Properties of the class Bar have the same names as the properties of the class Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Database schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TB_Foo
(
    foo_Id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,foo_Name NVARCHAR(20)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TB_Bar
(
    bar_Id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,bar_Name NVARCHAR(20)
    ,bar_FooId INT 

    ,FOREIGN KEY(bar_FooId) REFERENCES dbo.TB_Foo(foo_Id)
)
GO
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TB_Foo(foo_Id, foo_Name) 
    VALUES (1, 'Foo1'), (2, 'Foo2'), (3, 'Foo3')

INSERT INTO dbo.TB_Bar(bar_Id, bar_Name, bar_FooId) 
    VALUES (1, 'Bar1', 1), (2, 'Bar2', 2), (3, 'Bar3', 3)
```

When i try to use Simple.Data casting to object i get exception:

"System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been adde"

```
dynamic barAlias;

List<Foo> list = db.TB_Foo
    .All()
    .With(db.TB_Foo.TB_Bar.As("Bar"), out barAlias)
    .Select(
        // Columns for properties of class Foo
        db.TB_Foo.foo_Id.As("Id"),
        db.TB_Foo.foo_Name.As("Name"),

        // Columns for properties of class Bar
        barAlias.bar_Id.As("Id"),
        barAlias.bar_Name.As("Name") 
    )
    .ToList<Foo>();
```

Is there a way to achieve this? (sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Simple.Data uses its own internal aliases to handle the With clause. That's something I can take a look at in the next iteration, but the obvious answer for now is to rename your columns so they're not prefixed with the name of the table they're in. If the table columns have the same name as the properties, then you don't need the alias and everything will work.

What's the thinking behind the column prefixes anyway?

Comment: I don't know the reasons for prefixed columns but all tables on our production server have columns like those :-/